# What if only send without recv in my Thrift client?

Tags: networking, thrift

I'm implementing a Thrift client in order to make connection to a built-in scribe server.

Everything is going OK if I use a standard Log method, like this:

```
public boolean log(List<LogEntry> messages) {
    boolean ret = false;
    PooledClient client = borrowClient();
    try {
        if ((client != null) && (client.getClient() != null)) {
            ResultCode result = client.getClient().Log(messages);
            ret = (result != null && result.equals(ResultCode.OK));
            returnClient(client);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(LogUtil.stackTrace(ex));
        invalidClient(client);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

However, when I use send_Log instead:

```
public void send_Log(List<LogEntry> messages) {
    PooledClient client = borrowClient();
    try {
        if ((client != null) && (client.getClient() != null)) {
            client.getClient().send_Log(messages);
            returnClient(client);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(LogUtil.stackTrace(ex));
        invalidClient(client);
    }
}
```

It acctually causes some problems:

1. Total network connection to port 1463 (default port for a scribe server) is going to increase so much, and always in a CLOSE_WAIT state.
2. Cause my application got stuck without throwing any error, I think it may be an issue with network connection.

Answer (score 0):

> what if send without recv

As this is clearly TCP, the sender will block (in blocking mode), or incur EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK in non-blocking mode. **EDIT** It is now clear that you want to send without receiving the *reply*. You can do that by just sending and then closing the socket, but that may cause the peer to incur ECONNRESET, which may upset it. You should really implement the application protocol correctly.

> 1/ Total network connection to port 1463 (default port for a scribe server) is going to increase so much, and always in a CLOSE_WAIT state.

Lots of ports in CLOSE_WAIT state indicates a socket leak on the part of the local application.

> 2/ Cause my application got stuck without throwing any error. I think it may be an issues with network connection.

It is an issue with sending and not receiving.

Comment: Hi there. 

Thanks for ur reply. 


I just want to send an one-way request to scribe server, in order to improve performance for my application. 
Since it shouldn't wait to receive any result here. How can I implement this?

Comment: Just close the socket, but this may upset the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you labelled this as a Thrift related question, the answer is `oneway`.

```
service foo {
   oneway void FireAndForget(1: some args)
}
```

The `oneway` keyword does exactly what the name suggests. You get a client implementation that only sends and does not wait for anything to be returned from the server. This rule also includes exceptions. Hence a `oneway` method must always be `void` and can't throw any exceptions.

> However, when I use send_Log instead ...
>
> ```
>   client.getClient().send_Log(messages);
> ```

Neither one of the Thrift-generated `send_Xxx` and `recv_Xxx` methods are meant to be public. That's why they are usually either `private` or `protected` methods. **They should not be called directly**, unless you are sure that you know what you are doing (and very obviously the latter is not the case here).

And since the real question is about **performance**: Why don't you just delegate the call(s) into a secondary thread? That way the I/O will not block the UI.

Comment: Oneway should be a better solution for my case. Thanks

Comment: Hey,
There's a bug of thrift 0.8.x described at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1447
            
 So I need to use send_increase instead of ow_increase to simulate the concept of oneway request @@.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sure. Don't use 0.8. Most current at the time of writing is 0.10.